# How to use Buffer.from to create Buffer view

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create view of part of a buffer, after checking in node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_arraybuffer_byteoffset_length) I found that method `Buffer.from(arrayBuffer[, byteOffset[, length]])` should do exactly what I wanted. I started with the simple case but it already produces unexpected results so I'm definitely doing something wrong

```
var firstBuffer = Buffer.from('hello world');
var secondBuffer = Buffer.from(firstBuffer.buffer, 0, firstBuffer.length);

assert (firstBuffer.0 == secondBuffer.0) // fails

console.log (firstBuffer) // <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64>
console.log (secondBuffer) // <Buffer da 07 00 00 da 07 00 00 db 07 00>
```

How to create buffer view?

Comment: You probably need `Array` and `Dataview`.

Comment: To add more context, you should also specify the type of string to be ascii in your case `var firstBuffer = Buffer.from('hello world','ascii');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that result of `Buffer.from(string)` can have `offset` property different than `0`

Knowing that modified code works:

```
var firstBuffer = Buffer.from('hello world');
var secondBuffer = Buffer.from(firstBuffer.buffer, firstBuffer.offset, firstBuffer.length);


console.log (firstBuffer)  // <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64>
console.log (secondBuffer) // <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64>

assert (firstBuffer[0] == secondBuffer[0]) // pass
```

But it a shame that in official documentation there was no info about this "feature"